# Como eu renderizo um partialview ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma `View` que tem uma `div` e dentro dela vai uma `partialview`

**EX:**

```
<div>
     @Html.RenderPartial("MeuPartial");
</div>
```

No load da página renderiza certo, entretanto, eu precisava que ele renderizava todas as vezes que eu clico em um botão.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=@Html.RenderPartial("MeuPartial");>Atualizar</button>
```

o `onclick` não aceita o método.
Como eu faço para renderizar dentro da `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recentemente eu precisei fazer exatamente isso e depois de tanto pesquisar acabei optando por utilizar `javascript` para fazer o trabalho de carregar a `partialview` dentro da `div`.

**Javascript**

```
       function RefreshList() {
            var url = '@Url.Action("ListProduction", "Home")';
            $.post(
            url,
            function (data) {

                $('#listproduction').html(data);

            });

        }
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:RefreshList();" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh">&nbsp;Atualizar</i></a>
<div id="listproduction">                    
      @Html.Partial("ListProduction")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma Action para te retornar a partialview, e usar o jQuery [**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) para buscar e popular sua partial. Ficaria algo assim:

Action:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartial()
{
    return PartialView("~/Areas/Sua_area/Views/Shared/_MeuPartial");
}
```

E a parte no JavaScript:

```
$("#idSuaDiv").load('url_sua_action', function(res, status) {
  if (status == 'success') {
        //OK
  }
})
```